# One general sharing rule for a user with a role to share Contacts with their Managers

Tags: sharing, criteria-based-sharing

I want to set up a general sharing rule that any user with a role of "Area Coordinator" share the Contacts that they own with their Managers as defined by the Manager hierarchy field on the user. Is there a way to do that?

The org wide default for Contacts is Private and I have the Use Manager Groups feature enabled on the org.

I am trying to avoid doing a triggered apex share on every record.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Sharing Settings use "Use Role Hierarchy", you get this feature for free if you set up your role hierarchy correctly. Otherwise, you'll have to create a mess of public groups and creating sharing that way. You can't use the Manager field on the user record to cause sharing without using a trigger. Personally, I would advise configuring your role hierarchy correctly.

Comment: Appreciate your light on the matter! Looks like apex is the only way to go then, since in this org I would need multiple parallel role hierarchies that would be too difficult to maintain. And I am already using Account Teams to solve a different sharing challenge.